# ODP.Net - Oracle NUMBER(11,6) column is a System.Double in the data table

Tags: odp.net

Ran into an issue recently - We encounter an exception when we are trying to set a value in our data table. The exception is

System.ArgumentException: Input string was not in a correct format.Couldn't store <42.356> in COLUMN_NAME Column.  Expected type is Double. ---> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

We are using oracle client - dll version is 4.112.2.0. In the database the Column COLUMN_NAME is of type NUMBER(11,6).

We create the data table using **oracledataadapter.FillSchema method**. My initial understanding was that the data column will have the data type of System.Decimal. However the data column is created as System.Double - hence the exception. The even stranger issue is that this exception is not reported in our dev database, QA database or integration env but only in one specific client database.

**Is the data column being created as double correct?**
**What else could i be looking at?**

Answer (score 0):

Is the client in question in a country where the decimal separator is a comma, e.g. Germany where it should be 42,356? It looks like you might have hit a culture issue when converting a string to a double without specifying an explicit format.